# is there any way to auto configure the base/home url on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if there is any way to do this without reconfiguring everything , database o wp-admin `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` and instead of that let Wordpress to recognize the IP is comming from and answer?

Example:

If i set on my wp_home and siteurl some IP (behind a balancer) or I set localhost/ and I access my site from outside (example, a domain or another computer on the local network that connects throught the local network IP), no css will be loaded (because will call for localhost...../styles.css

Is there any way to auto configure this and let it "dinamic" without have to change it all time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can override the settings in** `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_HOME','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/path/to/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/path/to/wordpress');
```

or

```
define('WP_HOME','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

if it's always being served from domain root.

You can read more about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php).